# Adding elements in a 1 D vector

Tags: python, list, vector

I am trying to add the elements that are in a row vector to a 1X1 vector in python,
Problem:
[10 100]

Solution:
[110]

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, i just want to sun the two  elements that are in the list

Comment: You might want to read `sum()` [doc](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/sum.html) wich does exactly that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This could be done in one line:

```
example_list = [10, 100]

print([sum(example_list)])
```

Output: [110]

Answer (score 0):

Example provided in question is more of a list.

To sum up all the elements in a list, sum() function can be used.

e.g:
`sum([10 100])`
//output: 110